# How to upload .ipa file to server in html?

Tags: php, html

I am able to upload other file types like .txt, .png, .apk using

```
<form action="index1.php" method="post" name = "mySuperForm"
enctype="multipart/form-data">


<input type="text" placeholder="Application Name" name="appname">
<input type="text" placeholder="Version Number" name="appversion">
Application File: <input style = "width:auto" type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>

</form>
```

But, when I try to upload a .ipa file, I can't grab the application name or version number on index1.php (the page I am posting to)using $_POST. However, if I upload a different file type, I can. It's as if nothing is getting posted if I try to upload an ipa file, like the html is failing on that line. I am using my localhost, wamp server. Any advice?

Comment: Is the code completely failing? or is it reaching the index1.php and then the php outputs some error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your handling PHP, it's a bit difficult to diagnose, but here are a few potential items that may point you in the right direction:

- Does the .IPA file exceed the *post_max_size* or *upload_max_filesize* as defined in your PHP configuration?
- Try `var_dump($_FILES);` to see if your script is seeing the files there.

Comment: Check what your php max_execution_time also.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because the file is too big and the request is being truncated by the web server, so PHP would not be able to access any form fields because the request was not completed. How large is the ipa file? You might need to adjust your maximum post size. The default is usually 4 MB.